# If I delete a table row when the data is filtered should I also remove it from the unfiltered data? Angular - Template Driven form

Tags: html, angular, user-interface, angular-template

So I have a table of user data that can be filtered. If I apply the filter and then remove the data should I delete from the unfiltered data as well or just leave it? I was thinking I should, but I'm not sure if there is like a ui design guideline, or whatever it would be called, that says what I should do in this instance. Or is it just up to personal preference?

The way I have things set is up is that I have two sections of the html of my page. One displays filtered data if a filter has been applied and if no filter has been applied then just show unfiltered data. The filtered data is stored in an array and I use ngFor to iterate through the array. I have a clear filter button which will then show the unfiltered array.

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question. If they will never be able to view the data (even refreshing page) I would remove it from the unfiltered array. If it would come back after a refresh or clearing the filter, I would not remove it.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. I just wasn't sure if I should update both arrays if the filtered array got data removed from it. Like what if the user just wanted to remove that one row. And then once the filter was cleared its the same data and undoes removing that row once the filter is applied again. But I don't know maybe that's not something anyone wants to do.